# How to use specific discrete values for x when plotting several box plots

Tags: r, filter, boxplot

I'm trying to code box plots for "Yes" and "No" for a column 'alcagbi'.
The box plots I am getting are for yes, no, and n/a, and I want to remove the n/a values.

It looks something like this

sf36mcs:
4.45, 21.4, 34.9, 14.3, 74.1, 66.4 etc so is continuous

alcagbi: Yes, Yes, N/A, No, Yes, N/A etc so is discrete

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data=WHS, mapping=aes(alcagbi, sf36mcs))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[My box plots so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQTKL.jpg)

Also how do I get it so that the y axis only shows the positive values?

I am a student and still learning this software so any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: While reading the data, you can use `na.strings = "N/A"` in `read.csv/read.table` and after that filter `WHS %>% filter(!is.na(alcagbi))`. If it is already read, then `WHS %>% filter(alcagbi != "N/A") %>% droplevels() %>% ggplot(mapping = aes(alcagbi, sf36mcs)) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
WHS %>%
   filter(alcagbi != "N/A") %>% 
   droplevels() %>%
   ggplot(mapping = aes(alcagbi, sf36mcs)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Yes that worked thank you! Do you know how I could filter sf36mcs on the y axis to only show values on the plot greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Akrun got filtering out the N/A so I am going to borrow that code, but to filter out negative numbers

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
WHS %>%
    filter(alcagbi != "N/A",
           sf36mcs >= 0) %>% ###This is the addition
    droplevels() %>%
    ggplot(mapping = aes(alcagbi, sf36mcs)) + geom_boxplot()
```

If you want to exclude 0, make the >= a simple >